# Rust RangeInclusive<f32> step by certain value

Tags: rust, iterator

The following for cycle:

```rust
let min_pos = 0.0;
let max_pos = 10.0;
for x in (min_pos..=max_pos).step_by(0.5) { /*...*/ }
```

Fails with a compile error in Rust 1.68:

```
    Checking main v0.1.0 (xxx)
error[E0599]: the method `step_by` exists for struct `RangeInclusive<{float}>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied                                                                                                  
   --> src/main.rs:5:34
    |
5   |     for x in (min_pos..=max_pos).step_by(0.5) { /*...*/ }
    |                                  ^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `RangeInclusive<{float}>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
    |
341 | pub struct RangeInclusive<Idx> {
    | ------------------------------ doesn't satisfy `RangeInclusive<{float}>: Iterator`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `{float}: Step`
            which is required by `RangeInclusive<{float}>: Iterator`
            `RangeInclusive<{float}>: Iterator`
            which is required by `&mut RangeInclusive<{float}>: Iterator`
```

I would expect the step_by function is available to f32 as well as i32, where there are no problems.

Why is it not available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would expect the step_by function is available to f32 as well as i32, where there are no problems.

Why?

Integer mathematics are exact mathematics. If I start from 0 and add 1 three times, I get 3.

On the other hand, floating point mathematics are approximate mathematics, which can lead to surprising result. If I start from 0 and add 1/33 thirty-three times, I don't get 1 but 0.9999995.

This imprecision -- which accumulates -- is fairly problematic for loop constructs. It means that depending on the value of N, when looping from 0 to 1 by 1 / N the loop may execute either N or N+1 times.

To protect you from yourself, the `Step` trait is therefore not implemented for floating points.

Comment: Personally I tend to disagree(e.g. there are practical situations where imprecisions would be acceptable) , but if you can link an RFC about this, I would accept your answer!

Comment: Sure, just as there are practical situations where the subset of floating point values you've got implement a total order. Rust tends towards being pedantic, though. As for the RFC... I _wish_ I could find it, but it's not referenced in the [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42168) and my Google-fu fails me :( Possibly because `Iterator` predates 1.0, where things were quite less formal.